# Onscroll load more posts function skips a post in wordpress.

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I used [Load More Posts on Scroll](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html) in WordPress theme and it was working fine until I failed to notice that it skips a post on loading next set of posts. When the no of posts in reading option is increased it skips the other.. Linke, if n is no of posts and n+1, is skipped and from n+2 is loaded on the scroll. So how can I fix this or can we use a variable or something in which we can manually specify no of posts to load0?

Comment: Hey, @Manjunath, Please read that link comments from where you are code.
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

Comment: No actually its for custom pages also in my case the post is not visible at end also. btw im using mixitup plugin